# How to decrease quantity from database in item custom option

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, custom-options, quantity

I have some clothing items in different sizes such as **small**, **medium** or **large**.

Now I want to manage each stock separately e.g. **small 15**, **medium 25**, **large 30** without using configurable product option. Using this method I added quantity field in custom option and add quantity in database.

[Here is the link to add quantity in custom option in magento](http://bhaskarchoubisa.blogspot.dk/2013/04/add-qty-box-in-custom-option-row-magento.html)

Above link works perfect for me but the problem is arising on frontend, when we place an order of clothes in any size with any quantity, it will not decrease or update from our database.

What should I do so that quantity can be decreased from our database?

Any suggestions are very welcome! :)

Comment: I think it's impossible. Tried to google if there are new ideas on it. One of good answers on your question is here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/is-it-possible-to-set-individual-options-out-of-stock

Comment: May be its possible via programmatically, when we place order, in main inventory(product table) it decrease the stock where this function is running we put our statement and decrease quantity of item custom option from "catalog_product_option_type_value” table.

Comment: You can try to search other opinions on this topic. Why don't you use configurable?

Comment: I am a developer and making site for the client. Client doesn’t understand the configurable product process and thinks this process it quite lengthy. Client wants it to be simple and short.

Answer (score 1):

This is crazy, a solution will be expensive and error-prone, I'd rather try to educate the client or look for alternative product management solutions.

But if you really want to try it, you will need to observe stock change for your pseudo-configurable-product and adjust your custom stock database accordingly. Observing stock change is a tricky problem, have a look at the answers here: [Detect inventory change](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25207/detect-inventory-change/83178#83178)